# Parse.Push.send success probably called too soon

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to implement one time PUSH notification subscriptions in the Parse Cloud service. Here's my model:

- `Installation.user` - pointer to `User`
- `User` - `team` (`String`)
- `Subscription` - `email` (`String`), `status` (`String`), `user` (pointer to `User`)

As a user, I can say - send PUSH notification(s), to all my devices, when user with `email` became `status` and this user is in my `team`. User can have many subscriptions. User can unsubscribe manually (via OS X, iOS, Android, ... apps) or automatically - when user receives PUSH notification, subscription should be automatically cancelled. He can subscribe again, no problem, but auto cancellation is a must. These subscriptions are user based, user can see them on devices.

I wrote Parse Cloud function which consists of two pieces.

**Send PUSH**

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where : query,
    data : pushData
  },
  { success: function() {
    response.success('OK');
  }, error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    response.error({ error: err });
  }});
```

This does work. My `query` works and PUSH received.

**Delete Subscriptions**

```
deleteSubscriptionQuery.find({
          success: function(objects) {
            Parse.Object.destroyAll(objects, {
              success: function() {
                response.success('OK');
              },
              error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                response.error(err);
              }
            });
          },
          error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            response.error(err);
          },
        });
```

This does work. My `deleteSubscriptionQuery` works and correct subscriptions deleted.

**Combined Together**

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where : query,
    data : pushData
  },
  { success: function() {
    deleteSubscriptionQuery.find({
      success: function(objects) {
        Parse.Object.destroyAll(objects, {
          success: function() {
            response.success('OK');
          },
          error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            response.error(err);
          }
        });
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        response.error(err);
      },
    });
  }, error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    response.error({ error: err });
  }});
```

This doesn't work and success is reported. It seems that the problem lies in `Parse.Push.send`, ie. `success` is called too soon. I assume `Parse.Push.send` doesn't really send notifications, but just schedules them and `success` is called upon successful schedule. If so, should be renamed to `Parse.Push.schedule`. Also I assume that they are scheduled with my query (query saved, not really executed), so, I suspect this solution doesn't work because of:

- `Parse.Push.send` - saves my `query` and calls `success`,
- `Subscription` objects are deleted in `success`,
- Parse started to process my pushes with saved `query`, executes the `query` and it returns zero objects, because I already deleted `Subscription` objects in `success` of `Parse.Push.send`.

Am I right? Does anyone know Parse internals? If I am right, what do you propose I should do to implement one time PUSH notifications based on custom queries?

Comment: I suspect you're right, the API allows you to specify a date to send so is naturally async. Consider changing the query so you get all the installations first and then query to match the user of the installation from an array of users.

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but it doesn't seem _right_ to me. I mean, Parse can do it more efficiently internally (if it executes the query immediately) than me. But it's probably unnecessary fear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution based on @Wain's proposal.

- Fetch `Subscription` objects based on request parameters.
- `User` is included in this query, so, it's fetched along with `Subscription` objects.
- Make separate `Installation` query based on `User` objects from `Subscription` objects.
- Send PUSH to separate `Installation` query.
- Delete already fetched `Subscription` objects upon `success`.

I can safely delete `Subscription` objects in this way and it doesn't interfere with `Installation` query for PUSH notifications. Does work as expected.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("status", function(request, response) {
  //
  // Input validation
  //
  if (!request.params.hasOwnProperty("status")) {
    response.error("Missing status parameter");
    return;
  }
  var statusQuo = request.params["status"]
  if (!statusQuo.hasOwnProperty("email") || !statusQuo.hasOwnProperty("team") || !statusQuo.hasOwnProperty("status")) {
    response.error("Invalid status dictionary");
    return;
  }

  var status = statusQuo["status"]
  if ( status != "Available" ) {
    response.success('OK');
    return;
  }
  var email = statusQuo["email"]
  var team = statusQuo["team"]

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  //
  // Find subscriptions
  //
  var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  usersQuery.equalTo('team', team);

  var Subscription = Parse.Object.extend("Subscription");
  var subscriptionsQuery = new Parse.Query(Subscription);
  subscriptionsQuery.include('user');
  subscriptionsQuery.equalTo('status', status);
  subscriptionsQuery.equalTo('email', email);
  subscriptionsQuery.matchesQuery('user', usersQuery);

  subscriptionsQuery.find({
    success: function(subscriptions) {
      var users = subscriptions.map(function(subscription) {
        return subscription.get('user');
      });

      //
      // Query for notifications / installations
      //
      var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
      query.equalTo('channels', 'status');
      query.containedIn('user', users);

      //
      // Push notifications data
      //
      var pushData = { 'status' : statusQuo };
      var apsData = { 'sound' : '', 'alert' : email + ' became Available.' };
      pushData['aps'] = apsData

      Parse.Push.send({
        where : query,
        data : pushData
      },
      { success: function() {
        Parse.Object.destroyAll(subscriptions, {
          success: function() {
            response.success('OK');
          },
          error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            response.error(err);
          }
        });
      }, error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        response.error({ error: err });
      }});
    }, error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      response.error(err);
    }
  });
});
```